# Unit vector Normal to the plane.

Tags: mathematical-physics, electromagnetism

I am new to electromagnetics. I came across a problem where I had to find a find a unit vector normal to a plane. When points are given, it is the cross product, I understood that much. But, When the plane is given as 3x+4y+5z = 12, how do I proceed to find a normal vector for this plane?

My question is "HOW DO I FIND A UNIT VECTOR NORMAL TO THE PLANE 3X+4Y+5Z=12"

Comment: As you see below, if you know such an equation represents a plane and if you take constant as 0, which represents parallel plane, normal vector remains the same. So just take two different points on the plane and calculate the cross product of their radius vectors. So you do not need a formula (which in fact is elegant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a (hyper-)plane $P$ in $\Bbb R^n$ is given by the equation

$\vec a \cdot \vec x + d = \displaystyle \sum_1^n a_i x_i + d = 0, \tag 1$

where

$0 \ne \vec a = (a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)^T \in \Bbb R^n \tag 2$

is a constant vector, and

$\vec x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)^T \in \Bbb R^n \tag 3$

represents the variable point in $\Bbb R^n$, then for any two points

$\vec y, \vec z \in P \tag 4$

we have

$(\vec y - \vec z) \cdot \vec a = 0, \tag 5$

since

$\vec a \cdot \vec y + d = 0 = \vec a \cdot \vec z + d, \tag 6$

whence

$\vec a \cdot (\vec y - \vec z) = (\vec a \cdot \vec y + d) - (\vec a \cdot \vec z + d) = 0; \tag 7$

since any vector $\vec w$ which is tangent to $P$ may be expressed in the form

$\vec w = \vec y - \vec z, \; \vec y, \vec z \in P, \tag 8$

(7) shows

$\vec a \cdot \vec w = 0 \Longrightarrow \vec a \bot P; \tag 9$

since we assume

$\vec a \ne 0, \tag{10}$

we may form a unit vector

$\vec n = \dfrac{\vec a}{\Vert \vec a \Vert}, \tag{11}$

whence

$\vec w \cdot \vec n = \dfrac{\vec w \cdot \vec a}{\Vert \vec a \Vert} = 0; \tag{12}$

this shows $\vec n$ is a unit vector with

$\vec n \bot P; \tag{13}$

note that, with $\vec x \in P$,

$\Vert a \Vert \left (\vec n \cdot \vec x + \dfrac{d}{\Vert a \Vert} \right) =  \Vert a \Vert \vec n \cdot \vec x + \Vert a \Vert \dfrac{d}{\Vert a \Vert} =\vec a \cdot \vec x + d = 0, \tag{14}$

so that we may in fact re-write (1) in the form

$\vec n \cdot \vec x + \dfrac{d}{\Vert a \Vert} = 0; \tag{15}$

in fact, if we write this as

$\vec n \cdot \vec x = -\dfrac{d}{\Vert a \Vert}, \tag{16}$

we see that it may be interpreted as saying that the projection of any $\vec x \in P$ along $\vec n$ has the same magnitude $\vert d \vert / \Vert a \Vert$, which is the distance from the origin to $P$.

In the present case, we have

$\vec a = (3, 4, 5)^T, \tag{17}$

$\Vert \vec a \Vert = \sqrt{3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2} = \sqrt{50}, \tag{18}$

and we may take

$\vec n = \left ( \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{50}}, \dfrac{4}{\sqrt {50}}, \dfrac{5}{\sqrt{50}} \right )^T. \tag{19}$

Answer (score 0):

The vector normal to the plane is given by $$\vec{n}=[3;4;5]$$ and the unit Vector is $$\vec{n}^0=\frac{[3;4;5]}{\sqrt{9+16+25}}$$

Comment: Thank you. The 12 which is a constant has no real significance?

Comment: Not for the unit vector.

Comment: @WengChen As the constant changes, you just get parallel planes.

Comment: @WengChen Yes, different constant means parallel plane.

Comment: The 12 is a representation of the distance from the origin to the plane.  Really the distance is $|\frac {12}{\sqrt {3^2+4^2+5^2}}|$

Answer (score 0):

Let consider at first a plane through the origin that is

$$ax+by+cz=0$$

and the two vectors

- $OP=(x,y,z)$ indicating a point in the plane
- $n=(a,b,c)$

then the plane equation can be interpreted as the dot product

$$OP\cdot n=ax+by+cz=0$$

which indicates that $n$ is perpendicular to the plane.

Since a plane with general equation

$$ax+by+cz=d$$

is parallel to the plane $ax+by+cz=0$ (we can show that by a translation) also in general a normal to the plane is given by $n=(a,b,c)$.